# Javascript generator in a module/package

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, generator

I ran into problem with generators and hopefully you can help me out.

So, basically I separated/wrote my functions in separate modules (packages) so that it would be easier to update my application.

In the image below you can have a good idea what I am trying to do. For some reason when I keep calling the function with the `.next()` only the first yield is run.

[Code that isn't working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhtEv.png)

How can I run the other yields?

Comment: Can you please post your code as a code snippet instead of an image? :) Thanks.

Comment: From Review: Please also read this: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AlenGenzić I tried, but some how it keeps complaining that the code I post is incorrectly formatted. That's why I posted an image instead. The situation is exactly according to that image. I can call `sensorGenerator().next()` it only runs the first line.

Comment: Why are you using generators here at all?

Comment: @Bergi Im trying to complete a couple functions before running the next one. I tried it with async and promises, however, I noticed that some of my func arent ready at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `this.sensorGenerator().next()` create a new generator each time where you then call next function, returning same first value each time.

You need to create/instanciate your generator and store it in a variable somewhere, and then call its next function.

`var gen = this.sensorGenerator();
gen.next(); // first value
gen.next(); // second value
...`

Here is a working snippet showing how to do.

```js
const div = document.getElementById("osef");
const obj = {
 _generator: undefined,
 init: function() {
  this._generator = this.sensorGenerator();
  return this.getNextGenValue();
 },
 sensorGenerator: function*() {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
  yield 4;
  
  return 5;
 },
 getNextGenValue: function() {
  const v = this._generator.next();
  
  console.log("getNextGenValue", v);
  
    div.innerHTML = "generated value: " + v.value;
    
  return v;
 },
};

obj.init();

const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", x => obj.getNextGenValue());
```

```html
<button id="btn">Next generator value</button>

<div id="osef">Nothing yet</div>
```

Comment: I have been trying it like this a couple of times with no luck

Comment: Thanks @ESN ! You're a legend! Got it to work with this example :)

Comment: Glad i helped :)